# Text in moderncv’s left column overlaps with right column

Tags: spacing, positioning, columns, moderncv

I was trying to compile a Resume and I am not able to figure out why only the second line has superimposed text. The below is the code.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\firstname{Abhilash}
\familyname{Sukumari}
\email{asn@matan.name}
\homepage{www.asn.web.nsce}

\newcommand\Colorhref[3][cyan]{\href{#2}{\small\color{#1}#3}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Professional network}

\cvline{Linkedin.com}        {\Colorhref{http://www.linkedin.com/pub/abhilash-sukumari/10/8a6/1a4}             {abhilash sukumari}   - Professional profile and links.    }
\cvline{Stackoverflow.com}       {\small\href{http://stackoverflow.com/users/51197/adam-matan}             {Adam Matan}   - My software questions and answers. } 
\cvline{twitter.com}         {\Colorhref[red]{http://twitter.com/justnoticed}{@justnoticed} - My tech tweets.}

\end{document}
```

This is a snapshot of the output I have been getting.

[image: output]

Comment: NOTE : This code is taken from another source :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `\hintscolumnwidth` to something that works, e.g. 3cm. You can find that and much more in the extensively annotated [`template.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.tex) for `moderncv` that serves as documentation.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\firstname{Abhilash}
\familyname{Sukumari}
\email{asn@matan.name}
\homepage{www.asn.web.nsce}

\newcommand\Colorhref[3][cyan]{\href{#2}{\small\color{#1}#3}}

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Professional network}

\cvline{Linkedin.com}        {\Colorhref{http://www.linkedin.com/pub/abhilash-sukumari/10/8a6/1a4}             {abhilash sukumari}   - Professional profile and links.    }
\cvline{Stackoverflow.com}       {\small\href{http://stackoverflow.com/users/51197/adam-matan}             {Adam Matan}   - My software questions and answers. } 
\cvline{twitter.com}         {\Colorhref[red]{http://twitter.com/justnoticed}{@justnoticed} - My tech tweets.}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you. So using \setlength one can even adjust horizontal spaces between text. Is there anything similar to align the texts ? Like how we do in alignment of multi-line equations using"&" to stack them one below the other neatly.

Comment: @abhilashsukumari `\setlength` changes a length, in this case the width of the left column (the entire layout is sort of a table). It doesn’t directly or generally relate to the horizontal space between text, it just happens to have this effect here. With the alignment you mean e.g. making the left column left-aligned? That should be possible, but please ask about that in a separate question – we like to keep issues separate here on tex.sx, and while it is related, the alignment eventually is a different issue.

Comment: Thanks, if that's the case I will put that to a new question. And I see the way my question is edited and tailored. Looks much better. I will follow in these lines with my new questions. Thank you, it has been most helpful and encouraging.